# Relational algebra: How can I add up values from rows and create a new column?

Tags: relational-algebra

Let say I have some relation R1:

[image]

How can I create a version of this relation with a new column, 'Total', which adds up the scores in R1 for each person, then displays the total in a new column? Such as this:

[image]

**Problem:** Here there is no 'Total' entry in the relation. I can't just use some conditional (σ) to select it. I have to somehow create it with a summation of the Scores from R1.

P.S. I am using Relax tool if this helps: https://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/

Comment: Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. What are you able to do? What did your textbook or the documentaiton say about anything relevant? Is there an example like your problem? What call to any operator gets you closer to this? This is a faq--What did you learn googling clear, precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal? Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook/manual & do your homework & you have shown no reearch or other effort--not even reading the documentation page. PS "grouping" & "aggregation".

Comment: The operator is usually Group (wikipedia has `g`), along with 'aggregate functions'. The Relax tool has 'group by' in the tool bar: you don't seem to be looking very hard. BTW your relation `R1` looks dubious: If John has a score of 5 and 8, couldn't he have two scores of 5?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted.

Comment: @philipxy the question is a made up example by myself, so I'm not asking you to do my homework...I used images because I couldn't seem to make a table on SO so I made one in word and then inserted image. Typical SO response linking me to policy articles instead of trying to help.

Comment: Everything I said was to help you. Mostly to help yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Embarrassingly enough, there is a "SUM" function on the Relax tool, as described in some of their documentation:

[image]

http://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/help.htm